# SwiftyJSON Problems

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

I am trying to extract some data out of a JSON object I am pulling in from Reddit, and am having issues when using the SwiftyJSON library (you can find this here: https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON).

I am calling Reddit's API at the following URL, "http://www.reddit.com/r/aww/hot.json" I am trying to extract a few key value pairs out of the json response, starting with the author of a listing.

My code is below:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, NSURLConnectionDelegate {

    var data = NSMutableData()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.connectReddit()
    }

    func connectReddit() {
        let urlPath: String = "http://www.reddit.com/r/aww/hot.json"
        var url = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
        var request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
        var connection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: false)!
        connection.start()
    }

    func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveData data: NSData!){
        self.data.appendData(data)
    }

    func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection!) {
        var err: NSError?
        // throwing an error on the line below (can't figure out where the error message is)
        let jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary
        println(jsonResult)

        let json = JSON(data: data)
        let authorName = json["data"]["children"]["author"].stringValue
        println(authorName)
    }



}
```

You can see the code calling the SwifyJSON class, trying to parse it for data is the following, I am getting nil as a response when I clearly see data there.

```
let json = JSON(data: data)
        let authorName = json["data"]["children"]["author"].stringValue
        println(authorName)
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you look at the json returned by that URL you should notice that json["data"]["children"] will be an array of objects, not an object containing an 'author'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should try this ;

```
let authorName = json["data"]["children"][0]["data"]["author"].stringValue
```

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 3.0.1:

```
let authorName = json["data"]["children"][0]["data"]["author"].string
```